# Parametric Equations and Tangent Lines

Tags: parametric, tangent-line

I am running into an issue when I am trying to do this parametric equation problem. I tried solving it multiple ways but I think I keep doing it wrong somehow as I get different answers. The ones I have below are the latest. How would I approach this problem as each time I do it I get different answers.

Current Answers (Only x is right): x(t)=1-3t    y(t)=3t   z(t)=1+2t

Find parametric equations for the tangent line to the curve with the given parametric equations at the specified point.

**x = e^(-3t)cos(4t)**

y = e^(-3t)sin(4t)

**z=e^(-3t)**

Point: (1,0,1)

What is x(t), y(t), and z(t)?   *x(t) is 1-3t as that is the only correct part*

Comment: 1) If the point is (1,0,1), is it clear for you what is the corresponding value of $t=t_0$ ? 2) Do you know that a directing vector of the tangent line is $(x'(t),y'(t),z'(t))$ for $t=t_0$ ? 3) Besides, have you remarked that the 3D curve you are working on is a helix ?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I took the derivative with respect to t for each point, then plugged in t=0 to solve for the directional vector. Once I did that I just plugged in the points with that vector to get the parametric equations.

x(t) = 1-3t

y(t) = 4t

z(t) = 1-3t